# SSIS The parameterized sql statement yields metadata which does not match the main SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm getting the above error when trying to execute a custom lookup.  What I'm trying to do is lookup the minimum promotional price between date ranges.  The SQL executes fine in SSMS

```
SELECT  refTable.PRICE
FROM    ( SELECT    MIN(PRICE) AS PRICE ,
                    NAME ,
                    ITEMRELATION ,
                    FROMDATE ,
                    TODATE
          FROM      [dbo].[AllCustPrices]
          GROUP BY  NAME ,
                    ITEMRELATION ,
                    FROMDATE ,
                    TODATE
        ) [refTable]
WHERE   [refTable].[NAME] = ?
        AND [refTable].[ITEMRELATION] = ?
        AND ? BETWEEN [refTable].[FROMDATE]
                                      AND     [refTable].[TODATE]
```

but errors in SSIS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have mismatching data types to me.

Comment: In your Columns tab, what did you originally have?

Comment: Sorry for delay in getting back to this had a issue in live system, the issue seems to be with using the MIN function within lookup... it doesn't like it for some reason...                                                                   select * from (select * from [dbo].[YV_IG_AllCustPrices]) [refTable]
where [refTable].[NAME] = ? and [refTable].[ITEMRELATION] = ? and ? BETWEEN [refTable].[FROMDATE] AND [refTable].[TODATE] works but above doesn't.

Comment: I have added columns to original post

Comment: SELECT  MIN(refTable.PRICE) AS PRICE
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      [dbo].[YV_IG_AllCustPrices]
        ) [refTable]
where [refTable].[NAME] = ? and [refTable].[ITEMRELATION] = ? and ? BETWEEN [refTable].[FROMDATE] AND [refTable].[TODATE] works in SSMS but not SSIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was using MIN function fundamentally changes your source query (as you need to add group by etc.) go to advanced properties on lookup I made sure my source query was same as advanced query (without parameter filtering) and this sorted the issue.

Comment: would be awesome if you had actually posted the sql for your solution!